# Manually change document version in document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, versioning

I have a document which had 4 versions, version 3 and 4 are same so user deleted version 3 instead of version 4.
How can I set version 4 to be version 3? Is this even possible?

I don't want to upload document again because I want to have what was edited in version 1 and 2.

Comment: Cant you restore the deleted version from recycle bin?

Comment: I can, but If I restore it I will have to delete version 4. To delete it, I have to set version 3 to be default version. If I do that I will get version 5 instead of version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, version numbers auto-increment and cannot be modified on existing versions! Your only option is to upload all three versions to a new file in the correct order.

You can do this manually but will then loose timestamp metadata and possibly also author metadata if not yourself. With code you could copy all three versions to a new file and preserve metadata.

Finally, there are also third-party solutions that can help. My [CopyMove for SharePoint](http://www.sharepointproducts.com) tool (30-day free trial) can move the file with version history and metadata. The moved file will have all three versions as 1.0, 2.0, 3.0. The free trial will be able to help you at no cost.

Comment: I thought there is not OOTB way to do it, but had to ask to be sure. Thank you.